# Can we use GUI program in Vscode SERVER?

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-interface, server, python-turtle, vscode-remote

I am using VSCode server in my android phone . I was trying to use turtle ( python package) . But when I ran the code it gave error .

```
_tkinter.TclError : no display name and no $Display environment variable
```

So my question is can I use gui program in vscode Server ? If yes then How ?

Please answer it .
I will be thankful .

I was trying to use turtle ( python package) . But when I ran the code it gave error .

```
_tkinter.TclError : no display name and no $Display environment variable
```

I was expecting that code will run and program window will open .

Answer (score 0):

Hello @PrashantRawatCoder,

Turtle can only be used in a computer, since [the module it is made from](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)  is for making desktop apps.

TL;DR You can't.